# Proper use of Backbone.js and Marionette to group collections

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, collectionview

I'm not quite sure how to organize my Collection and Views using Backbone.js and Marionette. So what I have is a fairly simple Collection of Times (start, end, entry). I would like to display this collection as a table and repeat the layout of the table after every 4 entries.

```
Date    Start   End
0   08:00   18:00
1   08:00   18:00
2   08:00   18:00
3   08:00   18:00

Date    Start   End
4   08:00   18:00
5   08:00   18:00
6   08:00   18:00
7   08:00   18:00

Date    Start   End
8   08:00   18:00
9   08:00   18:00
```

What I have created so far is a CompositeView with a ItemView, however I'm not sure how to do the grouping and split of the collection.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y799N/1/

Html:

```
<script id="row-tmpl" type='text/template'>
    <td><%= date %></td>
    <td><%= start %></td>
    <td><%= end %></td>
</script>

<script id="grid-tmpl" type='text/template'>
        <thead>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>End</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="bdy"></tbody>
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
var Row = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#row-tmpl',
    tagName: 'tr'
});

var Grid = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    tagName: 'table',
    template: '#grid-tmpl',
    itemView: Row,

    appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView){
        collectionView.$('#bdy').append(itemView.el);
    }
});

var Time = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        start : '08:00',
        lazy : '00:45',
        end: '18:00',
        date: 1
    }
});

var TimeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Time
});

///
var times = new TimeCollection();
for(var i = 0;i<10;i++){
    times.add(new Time({date:i}));
}



var grid = new Grid({
    collection:times
});

grid.render();
console.log(grid.el);
$('#grid').html(grid.el);
```

Comment: This may help you http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-nested

Comment: I wouldn't split the collection at all, but write a custom `render` function for the `CompositeView`. This should be fairly easy: loop through collection, append ItemView and use a modulo operator to conditionally insert a row with the headings every x times.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way to do this is to modify the `appendHtml` function in your `CompositeView` to insert the headers whenever you want them.

```
appendHtml : function (cv, itemView, index) {
  var $childContainer = this.$(this.itemViewContainer);
  if (index % 4 == 0) {
    $childContainer.append("<tr><td>Date</td><td>Start</td><td>End</td></tr>");
  }
  $childContainer.append(itemView.el);
}
```